# Large XML file into MySQL

Tags: mysql, xml, xslt

I'm trying to import an XML file into MySQL. I've seen a few references to the questions already here and I've run through a number of them.

This is as it is being supplied by the client and having this changed won't be an easy or quick option, so while I'm waiting for a better feed file I am going to try and make this work. Hopefully with some epic help from here.

**Sample of XML file:**

```
<Feed>

<Product>
  <ProductCode>139244AAAZ4</ProductCode>
  <DisplayName>Men's Adidas Stan Smith Lifestyle Shoe</DisplayName>
  <URL>http://www.totalsports.co.za/pdp/Men's-Adidas-Stan-Smith-Lifestyle-Shoe/_/A-139244AAAZ4</URL>
  <ProductCategory>Court Inspired</ProductCategory>
  <Description>Created in 1971 for tennis star Stan Smith, this clean-cut men's shoe holds a special place in style history. A smooth full grain leather upper with perforated 3-Stripes and tonal rubber outsole have made this low top into a celebrated sneaker icon.</Description>
  <ImageURL>tfgsrv.wigroup.co/13/Detail/31417802.jpg</ImageURL>
  <latestSellingPrice>764.00</latestSellingPrice>
  <Brand>Totalsports</Brand>
  <ColourDescription>White</ColourDescription>
  <ColourId>31417802</ColourId>
  <SizeId>31417807</SizeId>
  <SkuDisplayName>10</SkuDisplayName>
  <StockAvailable>0</StockAvailable>
</Product>

<Product>
  <ProductCode>139259AABC1</ProductCode>
  <DisplayName>Junior Grade School Nike Air Devosion Shoe</DisplayName>
  <URL>http://www.totalsports.co.za/pdp/Junior-Grade-School-Nike-Air-Devosion-Shoe/_/A-139259AABC1</URL>
  <ProductCategory>Other Basketball</ProductCategory>
  <Description>The Boys' Nike Air Devosion (GS) Boys' Basketball Shoe rethinks the conventional high-top, with a dynamic collar designed to adapt to the constant movement and repositioning of your ankle during play.</Description>
  <ImageURL>tfgsrv.wigroup.co/13/Detail/31507661.jpg</ImageURL>
  <latestSellingPrice>899.00</latestSellingPrice>
  <Brand>Totalsports</Brand>
  <ColourDescription>Black/White</ColourDescription>
  <ColourId>31507661</ColourId>
  <SizeId>31507665</SizeId>
  <SkuDisplayName>2</SkuDisplayName>
  <StockAvailable>0</StockAvailable>
</Product>

</Feed>
```

Would LOAD XML be able to handle an XML file in this format, this is my first time taking on the Function and from I have read it won't work with it. Do I need to transform the XML first using XSL?

But also let me ask this, where is the right location to store a file for the INLINE LOCAL function sitting in the root of the server?

> LOAD XML INFILE LOCAL 'TotalSports Product Extract 50k Part 1.xml '
>   INTO TABLE XML_Import

Or is there another way of importing this type of data into MySQL on a regular and automated basis? This XML file is over 40mb big with bigger ones coming.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's so unique about this xml file? The sample data is in a pure record format, where the `<product>` tag identifies the records. There are not complex elements within a product.

Comment: Unique was probably the right word to describe it... sorry. Just having a really ongoing frustration with the client I am trying to work through. Let me edit the OP without the animosity. hehe

Comment: The `local` parameter makes MySQL to read the data from the client, not from the server.

Comment: That makes a bit more sense now. Removing 'local' I get the following response:

Error Code: 1045. Access denied for user 'admin_tfg_admin'@'%' (using password: YES)

Comment: Let me give it a shot, going to get the LOCAL version working first then move it to server. Thanks!